# How to get array data from Class

Tags: php, laravel, class

How can I retrive translations with country code from this class array and show it in my blade file? Lets say I have country code AF and then how I can return Afghanistan?

```
class TranslatedCountryCodes
{

    private        $translatedCodes = [];
    private static $instance;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->translatedCodes = [
            'AF' => __('Afghanistan', 'countrycode', 'myproject'),
            'AX' => __('Aland Islands', 'countrycode', 'myproject')
        ];
    }

    public function commitTranslation()
    {
        return $this->translatedCodes;
    }

    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (is_null(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }
}
```

I have tried

```
TranslatedCountryCodes::commitTranslation('AF')
```

I've been looking up some helper functions but cant figure it out

Comment: `commitTranslation()` must be static as well when you call it statically.

Comment: Correct call is `TranslatedCountryCodes::getInstance()->commitTranslation();`. But why do you pass something? The method has no arguments. You need to change it. `public function commitTranslation(string $country) { return $this->translatedCodes[$country] ?? 'not found'; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```php
TranslatedCountryCodes::getInstance()->commitTranslation()['AF']
```

Comment: I can't return it in blade file. Shows critical error.

Comment: @in2d What does the *'critical error'* state? In addition, in what *namespace* did you define this class? Lastly, what's your Laravel framework version?

Comment: The critical error is just from Wordpress. I am using namespace Database\Seeders. I am using Laravel 8.

Comment: @in2d Then, in your PHP blade file, try: `{{ \Database\Seeders\TranslatedCountryCodes::getInstance()->commitTranslation()['AF'] }}`

Comment: This will also run into critical Wordpress error.

Comment: Can't figure it out. I am trying to use use \Database\Seeders\\TranslatedCountryCodes;
$translation = new TranslatedCountryCodes(); but this returns error as well

Comment: @in2d I can't assist you without seeing the  *'critical error'* you claim to receive on your end. Sorry!

Comment: It's just Wordpress critical error. Also console log says 500

Comment: I think the error is because it's a protected function